# ngCordova and phonegap build

Tags: phonegap-build, cordova-plugins

Is it possible to use ngCordova with Adobe's Phonegap Build service?  [This article](http://phonegap.com/blog/2014/12/09/phonegap-build-new-features/) states that the phonegap build service can now leverage cordova plugins.  It specifies that plugins must be sourced from plugins.cordova.io.  So for example, in config.xml:

```
<gap:plugin name="com.phonegap.plugins.example" version="0.3.3" source="plugins.cordova.io" />
```

However, the docs for ngCordova typically only point to a github repository, rather than a hosting location at plugins.cordova.io, e.g.
    http://ngcordova.com/docs/plugins/appVersion/Is there a way to determine if a particular ngCorova supported plugin is available at plugins.cordova.io so that it can be included in phonegap's config.xml as a gap plugin?

I don't think that simply adding them to the project locally, for example

```
cordova plugin add https://github.com/whiteoctober/cordova-plugin-app-version.git
```

will work when compiling with the phonegap build service.

Comment: If you go to the Github pages for those plugins they often have instructions on including the plugin for PhoneGap Build.

Answer (score 1):

Short answer is no. You can't include it as a gap plugin. Workaroud is quite simple, though.

Download the [latest ngCordova plugin](https://github.com/driftyco/ng-cordova/archive/master.zip). Copy `ng-cordova.min.js` to your `www/js` folder. Add it to your `index.html` file.

```
<script src="js/ng-cordova.min.js"></script>
```

It is very important that the above line appears **above the `cordova.js` script**, otherwise you’re going to experience strange results.

> Be sure to use the same plugins repos from PhoneGap Build as they are mentioned in ngCordova documentation (from https://stackoverflow.com/a/26804250)